# negative lookahead regex to not match a certain pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to not match a string if it contains four dots or more in a row. This is my current regex.

```
^(\s*(CODE)\s?([0-9]{1,2}))(.(?!\.\.\.\.*))*$
```

So, my regex should match

```
CODE 7 Newton
```

But it should **NOT** match

```
CODE 7 Newton ....................
```

What am I doing wrong? It is matching all the dots even with a negative look ahead!

Comment: `^CODE\s+\d+(?!.*\.{4})` should work

Comment: @anubhava haha. you are faster than mr.flash on anything tagged with 'regex'! Thank you. Let me try this.

Comment: Please read [ask], and the thing you were asked to read when you tagged this [tag:regex].

Comment: @QPaysTaxes and your point is? I am not sure what to make of it.

Comment: @anubhava thanks bud,  you saved my day yet again with your lightning speed comment. If you could write your comment as an answer, I would be happy to accept it. But tell me something, in the expression .*\.{4} why isn't the .* greedily consuming all the dots? I thought that is how it is supposed to work

Comment: @Jay: `(?!.*\.{4})` is a negative lookahead and thus does not consume anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this reegx using a negative lookahead:

```
^CODE\s+\d+(?!.*\.{4})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eadet3/4)

`(?!.*\.{4})` is negative lookahead that **asserts** (without matching) that we don't have 4 DOTs ahead of current position.

PS: `.*` is greedy and does consume all the text till end whole asserting but it lets regex engine backtrack 4 positions back to match 4 dots at the end of the match.

Comment: But what if the dots are not at the end? What if I have text like this - CODE 7 Newton ....................2

Comment: Even then this assertion will correctly fail. End doesn't mean end of line. Engine backtracks as many positions as needed to either match 4 DOTs or fail the assertion.

Comment: You should check **regex debugger** option in the linked demo.